# Change grid attribute value on runtime in genexus

Tags: genexus

How can I change the value of the attribute in a grid on runtime?

For example, I have an **IsActive** attribute with a **boolean** datatype in a Transaction and I put it on a Grid in web panel. I want it to display as Text like 'Active' if the value is true and 'Inactive' otherwise.

Here's the screenshot: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLgz8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes in WebPanels grids are readonly

You can add a variable in the grid... char(20),
in load code, set something like this:

```
iif(StaffIsActive, 'Active', 'Inactive')
```

You are using WW+, here is a help for this:
[Grid Variable](https://docs.workwithplus.com/com.wiki.wiki?595,Grid%20Variable,)